# Finding cube of a number using macros

Tags: assembly, macros, masm, 32-bit, irvine32

How can I find the cube of number using macros in *MASM* (flat model). I have tried but can't solve it.

Here is my code:

```
include irvine32.inc

Cube MACRO Num  
    push ecx    
    push edx
    ;call readint   
    mov Num,al  
    mov eax,3   
    mov ebx,Num     
    mul ebx     
    call writedec   
    call crlf   
    pop edx     
    pop ecx 
ENDM

.data 
    var1 BYTE 3

.code 
main PROC   
    mov eax,Cube(var1)   
    exit 
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: show here what you have tried.

Comment: One: your macro can't expand to something that can be one operand to `mov`, because it's a whole sequence of instructions.  They don't happen at compile time!  Two: your macro prints the result to stdout??  This isn't unix shell, this is assembly language.  You don't get results from `var=$(cmd2)` command substitution to capture stdout, you leave them in a register!  Three: you macro only contains one `mul` instruction.  Four: the first time your macro uses its argument, you store into it (`mov Num, al`) rather than load it into a reg.

Comment: it means that I must pass two arguments in the parameters of macro 1 as input and 2 as output..??

Answer (score 2):

1. See MichaelPetch's comment for how to write macros that you can use as a source operand of an instruction.  You have to tell it what register to leave the result in.
2. your macro prints the result to stdout??  This isn't unix shell, this is assembly language.  You don't get results from `var=$(cmd2)` command substitution to capture stdout, you leave them in a register!
3. Your macro only contains one `mul` instruction, so you can't be computing the cube of an arbitrary input.
4. the first time your macro uses its argument, you store into it (`mov Num, al`) rather than load it into a reg.

If you want to cube a compile-time constant, don't use x86 instructions, and don't put the compile-time constant into the data section with a `db` directive.  Define it with an `equ`.

If you want to write a macro to place a sequence of instructions that cubes an input, it'll need at least two args: one input and one output.

You could end up emitting a sequence like

```
mov   Result, Num
imul  Result, Num
imul  Result, Num
```

Where `Result` has to be a register.  Or if you want to use unsigned `mul`, which doesn't have a two-operand form, then have the macro produce the result in `eax`.

If load-port pressure is an issue, or if your memory operand uses a two-argument addressing mode (which can't micro-fuse on Intel SnB and later), then you could have the macro use a scratch register so it only has to load once.

Writing a macro that pushes and pops to save regs is a terrible idea.  Just pass it some scratch registers as macro arguments.  Spill/reload them if needed in places that use the macro.

Comment: With MASM it is actually possible to do things like `mov eax,Cube(var1)` even with multi line macros. The key is using the EXITM directive to state what the return item is (a specific register, or value). With that information it can pre-process things like `mov eax,Cube(var1)` If your macro generates a value in _ECX_ and you wish that to be the return register of the macro then you can do `EXITM <ecx>`

Comment: You'd end up in my example with a bunch of macro code that emits instructions (that ultimately place a value in _ECX_) . Then macro expansion would convert a line like `mov eax,Cube(var1)` to a bunch of emitted assembler code followed by `mov eax, ecx`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks for the correction.  I haven't made much use of macros in asm myself, and never with MASM, so I was just guessing about what they could do. >.<